# Explicit cast when assigning pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting

In C if I write the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        char c;    
        int* ip;
        char* cp;

        cp = &c;
        ip = cp;

        printf("%p %p %p %p\n", cp, ip, cp+1, ip+1);

        return 0;
}
```

I get a warning about not explicitly casting `cp` to `ip`. However, the code itself seems to work just fine. If `c` had address `1000` I get `1000 1000 1001 1004` as output.

My question is why is the explicit cast needed. Is it simply because the C standard doesn't state anything about implicit conversions of pointers (other than `void*`) or is there something else going on in the explicit cast?

Comment: @Bathsheba Strict aliasing only kicks in if the contents of `ip` is accessed though, which isn't the case here. However, in case of misalignment, there might be UB for that reason, even when not accessing the data. But then this code won't even compile cleanly in the first place, on any conforming compiler.

Comment: @Lundin: Yup, I'm confusing C and C++ again. I'm such a cabbage head. Still, your answer says it all. Have an upvote, and I'll clean up.

Comment: Here are many examples of why you shouldn't do this:  https://www.google.com/search?q=sigbus+arm+site:stackoverflow.com  "But it works on my x86 system!" doesn't make it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> warning about not explicitly casting cp to ip
>   why is the explicit cast needed (?)

Pointers to `int` may have stricter alignment needs than `char *`. E.g. All `int` must begin on an even address, whereas a `char *` may be odd.  Other issues apply  too.

A cast tells "silly compiler, I know better and to just do the conversion - don't care if it causes a bus fault."

Tip: don't do it.

Comment: @Lundin Agreed.  [Warnings do not always work - unfortunately](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_dvHYqFZ6NH27FsziMP1lfbfIm2vLZTi_QFmtHmy1oQzL48at7Q)

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I was not aware that memory allocations might have different alignment requirements for different data types.

Comment: @Samik Note that a `int *` and `char *` could even be of different bytes sizes.  C supports many architectures, not only popular ones.  `printf("%p\n", ip);` can readily fail without a cast. `printf("%p\n", (void*) ip);`

Answer (score 4):

> I get a warning about not explicitly casting cp to ip.

You aren't compiling with strict enough compiler settings then. If you wish to get an error upon C language violations, you'll need something like `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors` or equivalent.

> However, the code itself seems to work just fine.

`char*` and `int*` are not compatible pointer types. Your code is not fine as far as the C language is concerned - `ip = cp;` is a violation of the "simple assignment" rule. And so your code relies on undefined behavior and non-standard compiler extensions.

> My question is why is the explicit cast needed. Is it simply because the C standard doesn't state anything about implicit conversions of pointers (other than void*) or is there something else going on in the explicit cast?

Specifically, because of the rules of how to use the assignment operator, stated at C17 6.5.16.1 Simple assignment, emphasis mine:

> One of the following shall hold:
>    /--/
>   - **the left operand has** atomic, qualified, or unqualified **pointer type, and** (considering
>   the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) **both operands are
>   pointers** to qualified or unqualified versions **of compatible types**, and the type pointed
>   to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;

The same rule has exceptions for `void*` and null pointer constants.

Answer (score 1):

Casting it basically just saying to the compiler "Trust me. I know what I'm doing." More often than not the programmer is wrong. If you only use casting only to suppress warnings, then you are doing something seriously wrong. And making an `int*` point at a `char` is just asking for trouble.

C has the nasty concept of *undefined behavior* which means that anything may happen, including the code working as it should. And that's the case here.

Here is an example of how it can go wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct myStruct {
        char a, b, c, d;
};

int main(void)
{
        struct myStruct s = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
        int* p = &s.b;
        printf("%c %c %c %c\n", s.a, s.b, s.c, s.d);
        *p=42;
        printf("%c %c %c %c\n", s.a, s.b, s.c, s.d);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
a b c d
a *
```

What has happened here is that because `int` is four bytes it will overwrite three other bytes when you are writing to `s.b`. Those are `s.c`, `s.d` and another byte we know nothing of. It's not hard to see that this can cause unwanted effects.

Comment: This is a great example. It would be worth an upvote if you explained *why* assigning 42 to *p  produced the given result.